# using mongodb aggregate groupby

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregate

```
db.getCollection('dbName').aggregate(
{$match: {"Request":"request"}},
{$project : {"PageResult":1,"ProductFilter":1,"BreadCrumbs":1,"ShowCaseHtml":1}},
{$unwind: "$PageResult"},
{$match: { $and:[ 
                {"PageResult.Brand":{$in:[/b1/i,/b2/i]}}
             ]}},
{$group: {"_id": {"Request":"$Request",
    "ProductFilter":"$ProductFilter",
    "BreadCrumbs":"$BreadCrumbs",
    "ShowCaseHtml":"$ShowCaseHtml"},
    "PageResult": {$push : "$PageResult"}}},
{$project : {"PageResult.CategoryID":1}}
)
```

Result of the query like:

```
PageResult" : [ 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60006410"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }, 
        {
            "CategoryID" : "60005202"
        }
    ]
```

What i'm trying is grouping PageResult with CategoryID so i add this lines to above query:

```
{$unwind: "$PageResult"},
{ $group : {_id : "$PageResult.CategoryID", count : {$sum : 1} } }
```

But it gives me this

```
{
"_id" : "60005202",
"count" : 6.0
}
```

Am i using $group wrong ,isn't the result should be like

```
 {
"_id" : "60006410",
"count" : 10.0
}, 
{
"_id" : "60005202",
"count" : 6.0
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: ok i'll explain a little bit more, after the aggregation i am using group method to an array and  the parameter is CategoryID totaly there are 16 object in PageResult Array and there are two different CategoryID  but when i use $group it shows me one of them

Comment: I fixed formatting.

Answer (score 0):

i found why i see this kind of result , a couple days ago i changed the batchsize (batchsize:1) in C:\Users\username.3T\robo-3t\1.1.1\robo3t.json file so it is normal that i see 1 result all the time i changed it default which is 50 i think, so it means my code works just fine.